# How can I extract raster values around points?

Tags: arcmap, raster

I'm using ArcMap 10. I have a point dataset and a .flt raster. For each point I want the sum of the raster values that lie within a certain radius of each point. i.e. I want to extract values within a given radius around each point and then sum them for each point. I just can't work out how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Spatial Analyst license, you could buffer your points by your desired radius. Then run 'Zonal Statistics as Table' using your point buffers as your zone features and the FID field as your zone field. Finally, join your point layer to your zonal stats table using the FID column.

Comment: This works fine provided all points are at least twice the buffer distance apart.  Usually, you're better off just extracting the values of a *focal* sum grid at the desired points: then there's no problem at all with buffer overlaps (and the algorithm is usually a lot faster).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. How would I extract the values of a focal sum grid at the desired points??

Comment: @whuber  Ah.. I've wasn't familiar with the focal stats tool. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Hugh, [ArcToolbox / Spatial Analyst Tools / Extract Values to Points](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Extract_Values_to_Points) should do it.